# how to resolve the following use case in angular 2 using Rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs5

use case is consist of three service call and service call should be in serialize.

1. get organization by ID.
2. Using ID to calling the **join** service.
3. After successfully joining than calling **markRead** notification service.

what i try is following.

```
  getOrgById(22)
 .flatMap((org)=>org.join())
 .flatMap(()=>notification.markRead(1))
  .subscribe(()=>{
  })
```

So the main issue is, how to get the organization information in subscribe.

Comment: You should use the .flatMap() / .mergeMap() operator if one http call depends on another http call.

Comment: What does `join` do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With observables of values, you could use `.do`, which takes the result of the previous observable, can do something with it and returns an observable of the same result:

```ts
getOrgById
    .do(org => console.log(org))
    .subscribe(org => {
      ...
    });
```

As far as I'm aware, though, there isn't a `flat` equivalent of `do` for observables of observables. You could get the same behaviour by returning it yourself from each step:

```ts
getOrgById(22)
    .flatMap(org => org.join().map(() => org))
                           // ^ like this
    .flatMap(org => notification.markRead(1).map(() => org))
    .subscribe(org => {
      ...
    });
```

Comment: one thing i want to conform that if error occur in  .flatMap(org => org.join().map(() => org)) so the next flatMap will executed or not?

Comment: @sasoft then write a test for it and find out!